# Error: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<## NASC'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to Read an Excel table into a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'E:\Impact\10_VD_Check-180619-004_testfile.xlsx')`
```

But I am getting error.Is it due to company's firewall??

> xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<## NASC'

Comment: Does the file open in Excel? Has it already been opened by someone else? Are you using a current version of pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct. This is due to your Company's DRM software called NASCA. It encrypts files according to your company's encryption policy. Generally the software encrypts excel files upon opening/saving the excel file and then decrypt it when it leaves your computer, e.g. if you send it by email to someone.

**Nor Pandas, xlrd, or any other python libraries/modules I've found support reading (or writing to) encrypted excel files.**

It may not be applicable to your situation, but I found that NASCA doesn't encrypt files unless they are opened - this behaviour may be dependent on your company's encryption policy, though. E.g. downloading an excel file from SAP, via your browser or FTP client; the file isn't encrypted and you can read and write to it as long as you don't open it in excel.